# Who is the wife of trunks?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-gt

I have a question about when future Trunks goes to the past along with future Mai but what about current Trunks I know that current Mai is his girlfriend but when he becomes young the Mai is so old in dragon Ball GT so he cannot marry her so who is his wife?

Comment: Woah woah woah. Who says you can't marry an old lady? Love is love baby <3! :D

Answer (score 1):

Dragonball Gt was not written by Akira Toriyama and as such is not considered to be a **canon** story.

As far as *Current* Trunks is concerned he has no wife, since he is only 8 and we still have to see what will happen with him in the future.